# How can I activate a automatic IP change in AWS RDS security classes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using RDS with postgresql and to access it I need my inbound data rules to be set to my IP. But everyday I have to go back into AWS to change it back manually. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to either get yourself a static IP so it doesn't change or specify a subnet that the IPs may be issued from (dependent on your internet service provider, it may be completely random every time).

You could also set it open to full public access from any IP address (`0.0.0.0/0`) but I would just recommend either changing it every time or getting a static IP address.

It has nothing to do with AWS.